# Radius and Interval of Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2n-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, solution-verification

This is my first time finding the radius and interval of convergence of a series, so please bear with me. I would like to find the radius and interval of convergence of
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{2n-1}\text{.}$$

My approach: by the ratio test, the series converges if
$$\left|\dfrac{\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{2n+2-1}}{\dfrac{x^n}{2n-1}}\right| = \left|x\left(\dfrac{2n-1}{2n+1}\right)\right| \to |x|<1\text{.}$$
Thus $-1 < x < 1$ and clearly, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: The series converges absolutely for $-1<x<1$, and conditionally for $x=-1$.

Comment: it is great. By the way, when writing this in an exam, insist on the fact that this proves: -convergence if $|x|<1$ - divergence if $|x|>1$ (and so $R=1$) -nothing if $|x|=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct in finding the radius of convergence.

However, since you want to find your $\textbf{interval of convergence}$ as well, you must remember to check whether or not your series converges on the endpoints as well.

In this case:

When $x=-1$, your series becomes: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\underbrace{\frac{1}{2n-1}}_\text{$b_n$} $$ 
Notice that $b_n$ is decreasing, $b_n \ge 0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$

Hence, by Leibniz's Test for Alternating Series, the series converges for $x=-1$.

Testing for $x=1$ (which I will leave to you) shows that the series diverges when $x=1$.

Hence our Interval of Convergence is $-1 \leq x < 1$.

Comment: By comparison, $\dfrac{1}{2n-1} > \dfrac{1}{2n}$. Thank you!

Comment: "Notice that $b_n \ge 0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$" These are not enough to apply "Leibniz's Test for Alternating Series", one crucial hypothesis was not mentioned.

Comment: $b_n$ must also be decreasing